PHP Klein router not working with localhost URL
I'm using Klein router to handle my raw PHP project which is built following MVC pattern. The issue I'm facing is when I browse my project in local environment via localhost URL it not load the expected files or content of the web pages. for example, http://localhost/myblog/home or http://localhost/myblog (home page).
But when I serve the project using php -S, example: php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/projects/myblog the URL works fine and as expected. I'm not getting the reasons behind this.
Sharing my latest code below,
index.php file
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$klein = new \Klein\Klein();

function r($method, $path, $handler) {
  global $klein;
  $klein->respond($method, $path, $handler);
}

// $klein->with('/myblog', function () use ($klein) {

  /*****************
   **** PUBLIC PAGES ROUTES
  ******************/
  r('GET', '/home', ['App\PublicPagesController', 'index']);
  r('GET', '/topics/[:topic_slug]', ['App\PublicPagesController', 'showTopicPosts']);


/*
  PAGE NOT FOUND ROUTES
*/ 
$klein->onHttpError(function ($code, $router) {
  switch ($code) {
    case 404:
      $router->response()->body(
        '404 Page...'
    );
    break;
    case 405:
      $router->response()->body(
          'You can\'t do that!'
      );
      break;
    default:
      $router->response()->body(
          'Oh no, a bad error happened that caused a '. $code
      );
  }
});

$klein->dispatch();

.htaccess file..
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/assets/) 
    RewriteCond $1 !^(robots.txt|ads.txt) 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

I'm looking for the clue or suggestion to fix the issue and can run the project using localhost url. Thanks.

How did you make sure that the rewriting module is actually loaded in your http server? And how did you make sure that this configuration file holding the rewrite rule is actually interpreted by your http server?

Hello @arkascha I have followed this link https://gist.github.com/RaVbaker/2254618 regrading the rewriting module which is basically suggested for Klein router.

That does not really answer my question. does it? I suggest you take away the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ... </IfModule> for a test. If you make a test request then and monitor your http server's error log file, what do you see? Alternatively place a definited syntax error inside that file for the same test, what do you see in the error log file?
